# How To Create Custom User dashboard Template On Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-shortcode

Have created a custom template page on my wordpress file folder through cpanel named user-dashboard and it includes 5 files on .php so, how do I make sure that every guest accessing any page on user-dashboard folder (e.g user-dashboard/settings.php) will be redirected to example.com/login   and login wordpress account.

Answer (score 0):

after your page creation process complete you add the below lines in function.php file

```
function user_default_page() {
  return '/user-dashboard';
}
add_filter('login_redirect', 'user_default_page');
```

One more thing is set your page can view after session set and your page path should equal of return path.